# OpenStreetMap default style for roads

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, xml

I'm using the OpenStreetMap plugin for QGIS and I've successfully rendered a .osm file (lines). I've tried a few styles from github but so far none of them label all of the streets like the osm default style.

Is the default style available somewhere? And what format should I be looking for for a .osm file, xml, sld, qml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out underdark's [various posts on styling OSM data in QGIS](https://www.google.com/search?q=osm+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Funderdark.wordpress.com). Most methods for advanced styling use the new rule-based rendering. You will want switch to the 'New Symbology' in the layer properties dialog to access it.

Style formats for layers in a QGIS project are saved with the .qml extension.